# Is the Hilbert transform of a Schwarz function essentially bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, fourier-analysis

My ultimate goal is to show that the Hilbert transform of a Schwarz function is in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, for every $p \in (1,\infty]$ (the definition I am using is $Hf(\xi) := \mathcal{F}^{-1}[(-i \ \text{sgn}(\text{-}) \hat{f}(\text{-}))](\xi)$, initially defined on $L^2$).

My strategy is: Given that $H$ is bounded (an isometry even) on $L^2$, and assuming it is weak $(1,1)$, I get the result for $p \in (1,2]$ by interpolation (this part seems like overkill; perhaps there is an easier way to do this). Thus, if I can show that $Hf$ is essentially bounded, I get the result for $p \in [2,\infty)$. My "proof" that $Hf$ is essentially bounded looks like this:

> By looking at the individual cases $\xi>0$, $\xi=0$, $\xi <0$, and
>   recalling that $f = \check{\hat{f}}$ a.e. for  $f \in L^1 \cap L^2
>  \supset \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, we get the bound $|H(\xi)| \leq
>  |f(\xi)|$ a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$; but since $f$ is Schwarz, its bounded,
>   and thus $Hf$ is essentially bounded.

Does my proof make sense? If not, is there anyway to salvage it? Additionally, is there a more elementary approach to the claim I am trying to prove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $|H(\xi)| \leq
 |f(\xi)|$ was a typo for $|Hf(\xi)| \leq
 |f(\xi)|$, but I don't see why you think that's so.

In fact since $H$ is a Fourier multiplier operator it's a theorem that it's bounded on $L^p$ if and only if it's bounded on $L^{p'}$. So on the plus side, having shown that it's bounded on $L^p$ for $p\in(1,2]$ it follows that it's bounded on $L^p$ for $p\in[2,\infty)$. On the minus side, this shows that it's not bounded on $L^\infty$.

Which is not quite the same as saying that the Hilbert transform of a Schwarz function need not be essentially bounded, since the Schwarz space is not dense in $L^\infty$. And come to think of it the Hilbert transform of a Schwarz function $f$ *is* essentially bounded. This is clear because $\hat f\in L^1$; in fact $||Hf||_\infty\le||\hat f||_1$. (Maybe that's sort of what you meant by the part I said I didn't get?) In fact $Hf\in C_0(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. That was indeed a typo, and I made my claim based on a misunderstanding of how the Hilbert transform is defined. This may seem obvious, but I'll ask since I don't see it: could you briefly talk about how you obtained the that bound $||Hf||_{\infty} \leq ||\hat{f}||_1$?

Comment: @Bachmaninoff That's clear: $Hf(\xi) := \mathcal{F}^{-1}[(-i \ \text{sgn}(\text{-}) \hat{f}(\text{-}))](\xi)$. The sup of the ((inverse) FT of $\pm\hat f$ is bounded by $||\hat f||_1$

Comment: @Bachmaninoff What I did was the quickest way to do the specific thing we were doing. But generally the FT is useless - study zhw's answer; that's the sort of thing that comes up when you start actually getting into the Hilbert transform!

Comment: Thanks, David! I saw your other comment as well; that's a neat trick. Also, why is it that FT is useless? (New to the subject, so I have a lot of questions...)

Comment: @Bachmaninoff Well of course I exaggerated when I said the FT was useless. But there's a lot to know about the Hilbert transform that can't be done using the FT.

Answer (score 3):

Home-made proof of that $H(f)$ is bounded: Suppose $f$ is in the Schwartz space. Let $\epsilon \in (0,1), x \in \mathbb {R}.$ Then

$$\tag 1\int_\epsilon ^\infty \frac{f(x-t)-f(x+t)}{t}\,dt = \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{f(x-t)-f(x+t)}{t}\,dt  + \int_1^\infty \frac{f(x-t)-f(x+t)}{t}\,dt.$$

In the first integral we can use the MVT to see the integrand is bounded by $2\|f'\|_\infty,$ hence so is the integral. In the second integral, Cauchy- Schwartz gives the bound $2\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}\cdot 1.$  Because $H(f)(x)$ is the limit of $(1)$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+,$ we have

$$\|H(f)\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)} \le 2\|f'\|_\infty + 2\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R)}.$$

Comment: Thanks for replying! I was able to reproduce the same bounds you have. However, I've not seen this characterization of Hilbert transform before. Do you happen to have a reference that shows that our definitions indeed match up?

Comment: I'm using the classical definition of $Hf,$ modulo a normalization constant. Google "Hilbert transform definition".

Comment: Right. Now say $\lambda>0$ and $g(t)=f(\lambda t)$. Then $||Hg||_\infty=||Hf||_\infty$, but $||g'||_\infty+||g||_2\ne||f'||_\infty+||f||_2$. So you get an improved inequality by taking $\inf_\lambda$ on the RHS. (Somewhere I learned a little trick: You get within a factor of $2$ of the minimum by choosing $\lambda$ so the two terms are equal...)